# one graphite node complaining "Error loading dashboard. Dashboard does not exist."

Tags: linux, graphite

I've got two graphite servers located behind an ELB in AWS. One of them is loading dashboards. The other one is complaining "Dashboard XX does not exist." I'm trying to locate where these are defined on disk (in conf files), but not having any luck. Any thoughts where to begin? As best I can tell, the two servers are configured identically, but obviously there must be some difference. The webapp logs are not helpful, they show HTTP 200 on the misbehaving server even though the pages aren't loading.

I should add that I didn't set up the servers and I'm not a graphite admin, so I'm kinda shooting in the dark here.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your dashboard, but IIRC both Graphite built-in dashboards and Grafana's (most popular 3rd party dashboards) are stored in database. So, you need to have shared instance of database to share dashboards between instances.

Comment: yes, it turns out we're using sqlite db for this.